# SQL query for 'past games'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm managing a basketball website with a game schedule feature. In the database, there is a 'date' column in `YYYY-mm-dd` format (`2015-04-10`).

I want to feature in my homepage a box that shows games with the same dates years ago (`2014-04-10`, `2010-04-10`, `1993-04-10` etc.).

Of course I can't use this query:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `date`='$date'");
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `<` rather than `=` ?

Comment: No, that will give me any games before today. I want games that happened in the same day, same month, just different year.

Comment: Even by the standards of SO, this seems remarkably obvious. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the day and month to match, then use those functions in the `where` clause:

```
where month(date) = month($date) and day(date) = day($date)
```

Note: it seems obligatory to recommend using parameters in the queries rather than inserting values directly in the query string.